# How to access Verizon FiOS Router when it is acting as a network bridge with my own router?

Tags: networking, router, fios

I have Verizon FiOS and would like to access the router that Verizon provided. The problem is that I had Verizon hook up my router to it so I could set up my own wireless network with my own hardware.

Everything works great, but I am having issues opening my NAT. I have the correct ports forwarded on my router (to my Xbox 360), but it isn't working. I suspect that I need to forward the ports not only from my router, but from the Verizon router as well.

My connection is like this:

outlet -> FiOS router -> my router

I can connect to my router at 192.168.1.1 but I can't seem to be able to connect to the FiOS router to check the settings in there.

Any idea how to do this? Or anyone know if I am correct in thinking that I can fix my NAT issues there?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the FiOS device is in routed mode or bridged? If it is bridged, then there is nothing you need to do with it. If it is routed, then you will need to forward a port through the Verizon device and then through your router before it will work.

I have read that the defaults on those are admin and password, but that could very well be wrong. In order to try to connect, look at your router's WAN settings. If you have a public IP, you are in bridged mode and you won't be able to get into it, but there will also be no need to port forward. If your router has a private WAN IP, then it's default gateway will be the address you put in you browser to connect to the Verizon device.